# generic cout that can be wcout depending upon typedef

Tags: boost, typedef, boost-mpl, c++

I've a `typedef char char_t` which can also be `typedef wchar_t char_t` and What I want is a generic `cout`.
I have a `util` namespace I want an `util::cout` that would be `std::cout` if `char_t` is `char` and `std::wcout` if `char_t` is `wchar_t`

Comment: What about having a "template <typename CharType>" traits class containing a typedef for the output stream? By default it would typedef to cout and then you could add a specialization for wchar_t where the typedef would be wcout.

Comment: But the problem is both `cout` and `wcout` is objects not type. What can hardly be done is different template overload will have different objects.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that. Then you could have an inline function returning a reference to cout or wcout depending on the specialization. Or go with static pointers as suggested by ecatmur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, no problem; you can do this with a template specialisation holding a `static` reference to the appropriate object.

```
template<typename T> struct select_cout;

template<> struct select_cout<char> { static std::ostream &cout; };
std::ostream &select_cout<char>::cout = std::cout;

template<> struct select_cout<wchar_t> { static std::wostream &cout; };
std::wostream &select_cout<wchar_t>::cout = std::wcout;

std::basic_ostream<char_t> &cout = select_cout<char_t>::cout;
```

Comment: Yes I was thinking about something similar but without const and * . why are you using `pointer` here ?

Comment: @NeelBasu good point, a reference works just as well and is clearer.  Fixed.

Comment: @NeelBasu well, if you're putting this in a header you'll have to separate the declarations and definitions, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

You're reinventing a terrible (at least in the here and now, perhaps it was a good decision at one point) design by MS.

Note that every other platform most likely uses UTF-8 for output, so a UTF-8 string through `std::cout` outputs just fine. On windows, Unicode output on the console is impossible to get right anyway (due to fonts and broken console codepages).

In short, there is no reason to *want* such a thing, and you're better off using one or the other, not both.

Comment: The problem is I need to parse unicode files as well. So In Linux I can use `std::string` for that, in Windows Iam using `std::wstring` and I cannot use wstring on cout. there will be compilation problem.

Comment: @NeelBasu You should be able to imbue your input stream so that it returns UTF-8.  Or you could just use UTF-16/UTF-32 everywhere (and imbue the correct encoding).

Comment: The "terrible design" that you speak of is using UTF-16? Yeah, hindsight is 20/20, but it seems like there are certainly far worse decisions that get made every day. What is your actual real-world solution to this problem? How do you write code that works on Windows?

Comment: @Cody: no, the terrible design being the whole `TCHAR` mess and API function defines dependent on `UNICODE` (or was that `_UNICODE`, or both?).  There's nothing wrong with UTF-16 over UTF-8. UTF-32 has some pros and contra's over UTF-8/16 though. The way I write code is use `std::string` internally as UTF-8 (though I don't give unicode much thought) and convert at the application/Windows API boundary using `MultiByteToWideChar` API and call the `*W` functions exclusively. This includes using Windows API calls for command line arguments. All in all, a very thin compatibility layer IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading files in wide format and using a multibyte program which i picked up from the comments, a solution could be . . .

You can read the file content as a `std::wstring` in to your programs memory and the use `wcstombs_s()` to convert the string read from the file in to a multi-byte character string.

Essentially it doesn't matter which format the string is you can always change it when and where needed.